# Can't run msi via two batch files

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

*(For a colleague)*

I have two batch files: let's call them `A.bat` and `B.bat`.

`B.bat` runs an msi. `A.bat` invokes `B.bat`.

If I run `B.bat` directly, it works fine, but if I run via `A.bat`, I get the following error message:

`msiexec is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I've tried the three solutions proposed here, with no success:

- [Register/repair Windows Installer Service](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315353)
- [Reregister/reinstall the Windows Installer](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315346)
- [Check/Reregister/reinstall the Windows Installer](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=324516)

*Just a minor detail, I'm on Windows XP embedded... on a 'normal' XP it works OK*

Comment: You may need to post some sample code from `A.bat`. For instance, if it altered `%PATH`, the problem might be obvious.

Comment: @Damien, thanks, apparently there *is* something else going on, currently bisecting :)

Comment: @Damien, you da man. My (non-developer) colleague had chosen `%PATH` as a variable name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Belatedly converting @Damien's comment to an answer:*

Don't use `%PATH` as a variable name!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the issue of an incorrect DOS path, you can launch `msiexec` via the builtin `start` command which will execute the command in a new window with clean environment variables.

For example:

```
start msiexec ...
```

Here's a fully fledged example:

```
C:\>set PATH=an-invalid-path

C:\>notepad
'notepad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>start notepad
```